# Decodificar qr code usando qrtools en python3

Tags: python-3.7, qrcode

Genere algunos codigos qr usando pyqrcode con python3 y todo perfecto.

pero al querer leer el codigo qr con el siguiente codigo que encontre tengo errores

```py
from qrtools.qrtools import QR 
QR.decode("1.svg")
print (qr.data)
```

primero me dio este error **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zbar'**
pero lo solucione con esto **pip3 install zbar-py**

cuando ejecute el script de nuevo el error fue

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "decoder.py", line 2, in <module>
    QR.decode("1.svg")
  File "/home/rtz/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qrtools/qrtools.py", line 156, in decode
    self.filename = filename or self.filename
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'filename'
```

**Estoy usando python3 en kubuntu**

Answer (score 0):

En python3 parece que la libreria qrtools no funciona correctamente.

Para python2, es necesario instanciar un objeto QR antes de ejecutar el decode:

```
import qrtools
qr = qrtools.QR()
qr.decode("1.svg")
print(qr.data)
```

Sin embargo, parece que hay problemas con la libreria zbar. Para que funcione correctamente [habria que instalarla así](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50538447/attributeerror-module-zbar-has-no-attribute-imagescanner):

```
sudo apt-get install python-zbar
```